# "which has been" or "which is" in a comparison

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction

It is the comment on YouTube describing Japanese anime called Naruto:

> Danzo is still a saint,compared to orochimaru who has ruined a lot of innocent life

In this comment, does the second half of sentence (parenthesis) equal "who was compared to…" or "who has been compared to…"?

Comment: Can you give a link for the same? Also, try to format your question in a better way.

Comment: Why are you thinking of adding extra words? If no reason you probably shouldn't.

Comment: if i have to add,what would it be? i just wanna now this kind of trasnformation..

Comment: adding anything here would change the meaning, as @Nathan Tuggy explains in his answer.

Comment: Also, there should not be a comma there, and that might be confusing you. The sentence should be "Danzo is still a saint compared to orochimaru ..."

Comment: (I'll repost as an answer if the question is reopened.) When we use the expression "compared to" as it is used in the example you provided, we are not referencing an actual comparison (i.e. a comparison that someone has already made); rather, we are speaking of a *hypothetical* comparison (as Tuggy mentioned in his answer). Further, we use this expression to convey the idea that something is not what we say it is, but *only seems to be when compared to something else*. For example: A flight from Seoul to San Francisco is short, compared to a flight from Sydney to New York. *(cont.)...*

Comment: *...(cont.)* Considered on its own, the flight from Seoul to San Francisco is not short (10-12 hours), but ***when/if*** it is compared to a flight from Sydney to New York (21-23 hours), it does seem short. We could also provide the same meaning/idea thus: "A flight from Sydney to New York makes a flight from Seoul to San Francisco seem short **by comparison.**"

Answer (score 2):

Neither really fits. The sentence means something more like "If you compare Danzo to Orochimaru (who has ruined a lot of innocent life), Danzo is a very good person." That is, it doesn't say "some people have compared these two" (as an event that happened), but rather "a comparison of these two would come out like this" (a statement of timeless, impartial fact).